# T-SQL FTS CONTAINS single character 'n' matches digits

Tags: t-sql, full-text-search, contains, sql-server-2016

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and faced to a very strange behavior.

I have a table indexed for FTS.

While searching by single character like that `... CONTAINS(N'"a*"')` it returns all records containing words starting from `a` - all right.

But if I search by single character **n** like that `... CONTAINS(N'"n*"')` it returns **not only** records containing words starting from `n` but also containing **digits**.

I can't google no mention of such behavior. I believe that this is a kind of wildcard, but there is nothing about this in the documentation.

Why is this happening? Is there an escape sequence or something?

**UPD**: test environment

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [ContentCatalog] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Content]([id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, [content] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Content] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC))
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Content] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Content_id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [id]
GO
INSERT [Content] ([content]) VALUES
    (N'abc def nop'),
    (N'zxc asd qwe'),
    (N'zaq nhy bgt'),
    (N'123 456 789'),
    (N'z12 x34 c56')
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [Content]([content] LANGUAGE 'English')
KEY INDEX [PK_Content]ON ([ContentCatalog], FILEGROUP [PRIMARY])
WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, STOPLIST = SYSTEM)

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Content]
SELECT FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled') -- should be 1
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Content] WHERE CONTAINS([Content], N'"a*"') -- returns 2 records
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Content] WHERE CONTAINS([Content], N'"n*"') -- returns extra record with digits only
```

Comment: Could you include a script to create an environment that replicates this for us to test with?  As there is no mention of this anywhere that I can find either, I would think there is something else in your set up that is causing the behaviour.

Comment: @iamdave Updated post

Comment: Thanks, though you would also need to script out your full text index and catalogue etc.

Comment: @iamdave Updated. FTS settings are default

Answer (score 0):

## This is not an answer which I know is against the rules, but I think it adds useful additional info that the OP may wish to incorporate into their question.

For further info, this only seems to work up to a certain number of `n` values in the `contains`.  The below uses the script in the question to build the environment but uses different test values.  The `select` then collates all values returned by the contains into a single row for ease of comparison:

```
insert [content] ([content]) values
    (N'abc nop abc'),
    (N'abc nno abc'),
    (N'abc nnn abc'),
    (N'abc nnnnbc'),
    (N'abc nnnnnc'),
    (N'1 2 3'),
    (N'10 11 12'),
    (N'100 101 102'),
    (N'1000 1001 1002'),
    (N'10000 10001 10002')
go
          select 'a*' as ContainsSearch,    stuff((select ' || ' + content from [dbo].[content] where contains([content], N'"a*"') for xml path('')),1,4,'') as ReturnedValues
union all select 'n*' as ContainsSearch,    stuff((select ' || ' + content from [dbo].[content] where contains([content], N'"n*"') for xml path('')),1,4,'') as ReturnedValues
union all select 'nn*' as ContainsSearch,   stuff((select ' || ' + content from [dbo].[content] where contains([content], N'"nn*"') for xml path('')),1,4,'') as ReturnedValues
union all select 'nnn*' as ContainsSearch,  stuff((select ' || ' + content from [dbo].[content] where contains([content], N'"nnn*"') for xml path('')),1,4,'') as ReturnedValues
union all select 'nnnn*' as ContainsSearch, stuff((select ' || ' + content from [dbo].[content] where contains([content], N'"nnnn*"') for xml path('')),1,4,'') as ReturnedValues
union all select 'nnnnn*' as ContainsSearch,stuff((select ' || ' + content from [dbo].[content] where contains([content], N'"nnnnn*"') for xml path('')),1,4,'') as ReturnedValues
```

Which results in:

```
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ContainsSearch |                                                             ReturnedValues                                                              |
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| a*             | abc nop abc || abc nno abc || abc nnn abc || abc nnnnbc || abc nnnnnc                                                                   |
| n*             | abc nop abc || abc nno abc || abc nnn abc || abc nnnnbc || abc nnnnnc || 10 11 12 || 100 101 102 || 1000 1001 1002 || 10000 10001 10002 |
| nn*            | abc nno abc || abc nnn abc || abc nnnnbc || abc nnnnnc || 10 11 12 || 100 101 102 || 1000 1001 1002 || 10000 10001 10002                |
| nnn*           | abc nnn abc || abc nnnnbc || abc nnnnnc                                                                                                 |
| nnnn*          | abc nnnnbc || abc nnnnnc                                                                                                                |
| nnnnn*         | abc nnnnnc                                                                                                                              |
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what is going on here and given the lack of *anything* relevant in the documentation you may well have hit a bug...

Comment: I made bug report https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/34442179-full-text-search-contains-single-character-n-mat